# PHP seems to execute one particular line of code in a false if

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I hope someone here can help me out because I'm stumped on this weird bug in my PHP code.
First, here's the relevant part of the code:

```
//STEP 1b - PREPROCESSING OF SUBMITTED FORM DATA (table level)
while($count_table++ != $num_tables && $submit != ""){

$table_show[$count_table] = mysql_escape_string($_POST[table_show_.$count_table]);
$ne_page[$count_table] = mysql_escape_string($_POST[ne_page_.$count_table]);

}

//STEP 2 - SUBMITTED?
if($submit!=""){

//The form has been submitted

//STEP 3 - VALIDATION

    //Reset counts
    $count_column = 0;
    $count_table = 0;

    //Check for empty fields
    while($count_table++ != $num_tables){ if($table_show[$count_table] != ""){ //While there are tables, validate only if they are in included in NexEdit
```

This is where, in a scenario I'm testing, the if returns a false value. As a result, it should just go straight back to the while in front of it (I close the while and if at the same point further on).

```
        if($ne_page[$count_table] == ""){
                $error = "You forgot to give a NexEdit name to one or more of the tables you want to include in NexEdit.";
        }

        echo "Debug";
```

As expected, this is never echoed, because PHP never entered the if earlier on in the first place.

```
                    while($db_field[++$count_column]){ //Stay inside the loop until we run out of db fields
            if($db_field[$count_column] == "" || $db_type[$count_column] == "" || $db_table[$count_column] == "" || $ne_name[$count_column] == "" || $ne_type[$count_column] == "" || $ne_order[$count_column] == ""){ //Check if all information is entered if the column is selected to be included in NexEdit
                $error = "You didn't enter all required information. Required fields are indicated with (*).";
```

**This is where the bug happens:** even though PHP shouldn't have entered the if earlier on (as demonstrated with the debug echo), it still sets the value of $error here.

```
            }
        }
    }}

//More code...
```

What am I missing? I've been looking at this for hours and even asked a friend developer for help, but I just can't find what I did wrong.

---

All code in one block:

```
//STEP 1b - PREPROCESSING OF SUBMITTED FORM DATA (table level)
while($count_table++ != $num_tables && $submit != ""){

$table_show[$count_table] = mysql_escape_string($_POST[table_show_.$count_table]);
$ne_page[$count_table] = mysql_escape_string($_POST[ne_page_.$count_table]);

}

//STEP 2 - SUBMITTED?
if($submit!=""){

//The form has been submitted

//STEP 3 - VALIDATION

    //Reset counts
    $count_column = 0;
    $count_table = 0;

    //Check for empty fields
    while($count_table++ != $num_tables){ if($table_show[$count_table] != ""){ //While there are tables, validate only if they are in included in NexEdit

        if($ne_page[$count_table] == ""){
                $error = "You forgot to give a NexEdit name to one or more of the tables you want to include in NexEdit.";
        }

        echo "Debug";

                    while($db_field[++$count_column]){ //Stay inside the loop until we run out of db fields
            if($db_field[$count_column] == "" || $db_type[$count_column] == "" || $db_table[$count_column] == "" || $ne_name[$count_column] == "" || $ne_type[$count_column] == "" || $ne_order[$count_column] == ""){ //Check if all information is entered if the column is selected to be included in NexEdit
                $error = "You didn't enter all required information. Required fields are indicated with (*).";

            }
        }
    }}

//More code...
```

Comment: Why don't you start by using empty or is_null instead of != "", and for other checks do !==, so you can check type as well.  That will help you debug more effectively.  Man, honestly I can't really tell what's going on here.  Could you put all the relevant code in one block?  Hard to help you without context.

Comment: You can also put the checks into a `var_dump()` to see what they evaluate to. For example `var_dump($ne_page[$count_table] == "");` would output true or false.

Comment: I just added the entire chunk of code in one block in the original post. I'll try out your suggestions as well and I'll report back to you asap.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be a mismatched curly brace somewhere.

You say that "it should just go straight back into the while in front of it". Unless I am mistaken, it looks like that while loop closes before the if statement.

Would a more full/unchopped version of the method be possible to post? It may help diagnose

Comment: I just checked for mismatched curly braces but they all match. I checked this earlier as well and even had someone else check it to make sure I wasn't missing something.

I added an unchopped code block to the original question.

Comment: Which error is being returned?  That would show us which if is being unintentionally executed.

Comment: The error that's returned (and that shouldn't appear) is the second: "You didn't enter all required information. Required fields are indicated with (*)."

In fact, the first error doesn't show up in a similar scenario. Which is pretty strange.

Comment: Can you post the output after adding a var_dump() for each of the fields you check in that if?

Comment: Alright, I will. I'm using var_dump() right now to see if I can find the error myself. Just a moment!

Comment: The if-statement after the first while I annotated (aka: `if($table_show[$count_table] != "")`) only returns bool(true) but not bool(false), so I think we tracked down the bug! :D

Comment: So the script does echo "Debug" after all?

Comment: Should that not be true? I was referring to the if statement after the echo "Debug"

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had some things to figure out. I tracked down the problem: apparently the if statement is executed even if its value is false for some reason. I'm checking for curly bracket mistakes again.

Comment: Okay, so I think I've got the problem narrowed down to this: the following if-statement only returns a true, but not a false. As a result, it is executed even if it doesn't return a true. `if($table_show[$count_table] != "")`

Comment: Yes. I think if you do a var_dump() of that variable, it probably isnt == "" in the case where it fails. It may have an error, null, or something else in it. Anything but "" for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$error` is never cleared during the `while` loop(s). So, where you think it's being filled is actually the result of one of the previous iterations of the `while` loop.

Comment: This is actually by design. I don't use the error value until later on in the code so it should not be cleared in the while loop yet.

Comment: It won't return an $error for any other case in the while loop because in the scenario I tested, there's only one value that doesn't validate.